# How can I create a combo box from an object that has an arraylist of objects in javafx?

Tags: javafx, combobox

If I have an object that has an arrayList of objects:

```
class Event{        
    private ArrayList<Room> rooms;
    //..
    public void setRooms(ArrayList<Room> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public ArrayList<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

//---------------------

```
class Room{
    private String roomId;
    private String roomName;

    public Room(String roomId, String roomName) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
        this.roomName = roomName;
    }

    public String getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }

    public String getRoomName() {
         return roomName;
    }

    public void setRoomId(String roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }

    public void setRoomName(String roomName) {
         this.roomName = roomName;
    }
}
```

**How can I create a combobox in my table from the array of room objects?**

What I have that is only showing an object identifier of some sort.

```
TableColumn<Event, ArrayList> roomsColumn = new TableColumn<>("Room Select");
roomsColumn.setMinWidth(200);
roomsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rooms"));

//Create an observable list to populate the table with.
ObservableList<Event> eventList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//loop the json to populate the observable list
for (Event event : events.getEventList() ){
   eventList.add(event);
}

//populate the table
eventTable.setItems(eventList);
eventTable.getColumns().addAll(eventColumn, bDateColumn, eDateColumn, roomsColumn);
```

**All of the columns are built but the rooms column shows a comma separated list of room objects:

```
com.***.Room@345, com.***.Room@653, com.***.Room@889
```

Comment: It is confusing why you would make a `TableCell` render a list, with a `ComboBox`. Is your table meant for user to read data, or to collect data?

Comment: If it is meant for display (read) data, then the `rooms` list should be rendered as a simple `Label`, probably through concatenation of `roomName`. If it is supposed to be used for data collection, you would expect user to choose one room only, so `Event` class holding a list of `rooms` would be wrong - you would probably need to create a separate model class that would be used to store collected data.

Comment: I want the user to be able to select from a list of rooms.. The row would be event, event date, event time, (comboBox) event rooms

Comment: @Jai The data is coming from an api that holds the rooms as a nested array inside of the event. The way I understand GSON is that my objects need to match the JSON data model. So that is why i have Rooms as an array of room objects inside of Event. Does that sound more correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom cell factory to return a TableCell with a ComboBox.

```
    roomsColumn.setCellFactory(call -> {
        // create a new cell for array lists
        return new TableCell<Event, ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override 
            protected void updateItem(ArrayList<String> item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                // if there is no item, return an empty cell
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } 
                else {
                    ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>();
                    // set combo box items
                    box.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(item));
                    // listen for changes
                    box.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        System.out.println("new room "+newValue);
                    });
                    // set cell contents
                    setGraphic(box);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks B.Thomas.. I am getting the events and rooms from an API that supplies a JSON string. So the only reason I have Rooms as an arraylist inside of Event is because I was under the impression that GSON needed the classes to match the JSON data that I get which has the rooms nested inside the Event. I do have a getter and setter for the ArrayList. See update to my question for the getter and setter

Comment: Hi B. Thomas. This works! I don't fully understand it yet but it puts the combobox where I need it. Thanks! One question. Is the combobox aware of the object it references? Will I be able to select an option and get the object?

Comment: It is aware of the ArrayList, but not the parent Event.

Comment: Hi.. I am getting an error when I select. It is saying that the room object can not be cast as a string.. (I had to put this aside for a couple of weeks and just got back to it)